# Learning Bernoulli Parameter (problem related to a Quantum Algorithm)

Tags: probability, statistical-inference, machine-learning, quantum-computation

The [LGZ algorithm](https://www.nature.com/articles/ncomms10138) for Topological Data Analysis via computing Betti Numbers is a quantum algorithm that relies on sampling random eigenvalues of an appropriate linear operator. The expected fraction of these eigenvalues that are 0 is equal to the *normalised* Betti Number.

My question concerns how many samples of random eigenvalues one would need to be confident that the estimator (i.e. the ratio of eigenvalues that are 0 in the sample) is close to its true value (the *normalised Betti Number*.

Abstracting away all details of quantum algorithms, the problem is effectively the following: Suppose we have a coin with some unknown probability of heads (p).

We make N flips of the coin with the aim of knowing p to within error ±ϵ, and with probability of failure <δ. For a given target of (ϵ,δ), how many flips N do we need to make?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The answer is
$$
\Theta\left( \frac{\log(1/\delta)}{\varepsilon^2} \right)
$$
for a uniform minimax bound. The upper bound follows from a Hoeffding bound; for the lower bound, you can derive it from the "simpler" testing question, as, e.g., outlined in [this Wikipedia article](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bretagnolle-Huber_inequality#Sample_complexity_of_biased_coin_tosses%5B1%5D). You can have a local minimax version as well, if that's what you want, with a dependence on the (unknown) parameter $p$ in the bound; [see, e.g., this question](https://cstheory.stackexchange.com/questions/38929/learning-a-coins-bias-localized).

Comment: Hi thank you for your answer! The wikipedia link you mention isn't correctly linked - could you please fix that?

Comment: @shashvat My bad: it should be fixed now.